# Mysql query with ability to "step" across or "skip" datetimes at interval based on results of query

Tags: mariadb

Using Mariadb

The database records are "available" times a user can be scheduled that step by 5 minutes:

Example

> 10:00:00
> 10:05:00
> 10:10:00
> 10:15:00
> 10:20:00
> 10:25:00

A user's meeting length is 90 minutes.
Every user's "first" start time is different per day, so it cannot be hard coded as the main query pulls 30 days worth of data.

I have tried using intervals and variables with no luck. Ideally, the output should become:

> 10:00:00
> 11:30:00
> 13:00:00

But for user #2 it may be

> 10:30:00
> 12:00:00
> 13:30:00

So what can be used in the query to determine the FIRST time listed, and only show the next available record that is >= 90 minutes later than previous time.

This query DOES NOT work, just an idea of how i am trying to work this.

```
SELECT mettingtime 
FROM `availabletimes` 
WHERE active=1 
  AND DATE_FORMAT(mettingtime,'%T')>=ADDTIME(DATE_FORMAT(PreviousRecord.mettingtime,'%T'), 90)
```

Comment: [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055)

Comment: Also see [application time periods without overlaps](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/application-time-periods/#without-overlaps) before you implement your own buggy solution in an application langugage.